# Why is my Razor @if statement not adding a script tag even when the condition is met?

Tags: c#, asp.net, razor-pages

I have a fairly simple if condition in some Razor syntax in a view:

```
@if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Model.AddThisKey))
{
    <script type="text/javascript" src="@Model.AddThisKey"></script>
}
```

Pretty simple - if the model property is not empty or null: add the script tag.

When I step through this in the debugger, Model.AddThisKey has a value. It's a string variable. When I step next (F10) it goes to the open brace, indicating it knows the string is not null. Then it skips straight to the end brace and does not add the script tag.

Can anyone tell me why? I'm truly baffled.

It should work. Right?

Comment: It will work. Please check whether is there any console error. And also check two things, 1. Whether "@Model.AddThisKey" has valid JS file path? 2. Go to Developer tools -> inspect elements check whether the script is present in elements or not.

Answer (score 0):

This should render the tag exactly as intended (even within a script block):

```
@if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Model.AddThisKey))
{
<text>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="@Model.AddThisKey"></script>
</text>
}
```